# Angular filter not render in view after output changed

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have an angular filter which is formatting its output by the value of some global variable. That one can change asynchronously, and so do the result of the filter. However, the result is not rendered into view. Not event dispatching `$apply()` on `$scope` or even `$rootScope`, would force view to render the new output of this filter.

For me, it seems like that since filters input stays the same for the whole time, angular won't call filters own method (sort of optimisation there, I guess).

Here is a plunker with the minimal demonstration:

https://plnkr.co/edit/aUm0XRzWn1qr8ZFZB2sY?p=preview

There is a workaround by encapsulating filter inside method (on controllers or $scope) which would render in each time view redraws. But it forces me to redeclaring this method in every controller on view that require use of this filter.

Did anyone also encounter this limitation with filters?

This is happening in every angular version I've tested from 1.2.x to 1.5.x

Comment: Could use a service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can be solved with a stateful filter.

From the Docs:

> ### Stateful filters
>
> It is strongly discouraged to write filters that are stateful, because the execution of those can't be optimized by Angular, which often leads to performance issues. Many stateful filters can be converted into stateless filters just by exposing the hidden state as a model and turning it into an argument for the filter.
>
> If you however do need to write a stateful filter, you have to mark the filter as `$stateful`, which means that it will be executed one or more times during the each `$digest` cycle.

--[AngularJS Developer Guide -- Stateful filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#stateful-filters)

### JS

```
app.filter('myFilter', function() {
  function myFilter() {
      return someValue
  }
  //Set filter to $stateful
  myFilter.$stateful = true;
  //
  return myFilter;
})
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/E22NSykeLYyUAKbFKM00?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Or if you don't want to make the filter stateful you can make use of a service
that you inject in both filter and controller. (Which is pretty much standard in angular when you want to share any data between anything and anything)
https://plnkr.co/edit/GUth5licV3ubLUf2maTV?p=preview

```
.factory('testService', function(){
  return { 
    someValue : 'This is not right',
    update : function(str){ this.someValue = str; }
  };
})

.filter('myFilter', function( testService ) {
  // Your problem is that this function "lives on" the way it was created
  return function() {
    return testService.someValue;
  }
})

.controller('myController', function($scope, $filter, testService) {
  testService.update( 'This is OK');

  $scope.myMethodCallingMyFilter = function() {
    return $filter('myFilter')();
  };
})
```